# Change input type when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change input type to `text` from `password` when I click the "Show password" checkbox.

This what I have written. Is it correct?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementsByClassName('password').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"> Show password
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $("#check").on("change", function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(".password").attr("type", "text");
        } else {
            $(".password").attr("type", "password");
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<input type="checkbox" id='check'> Show password
```

You need to provide id to the checkbox and on the change event, it checks if the checkbox is checked or not, if yes then it will make the `.password` class field input to text otherwise it will be password

Answer (score 6):

In pure javascript you can do like this,
`getElementsByClassName('password')` will give you collection of nodes. You have to iterate it and apply the changes to each.

`forEach()` can not applied to collection, so `Array.from(...)` used here to create array from the node collection.

```js
function doSomething(isChecked) {
  var type = isChecked ? 'text' : 'password';
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('password')).forEach(element => {
    element.type = type;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<input type="password" class="password"/>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="doSomething(this.checked)"> Show password
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
```

```html
   



Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput"><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer actually does.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="myform">
           <input type="text" name="txt" />
           <input type="checkbox" name="option" value='1' onchange="changeType()" />
        </form>
        <script>
            function changeType()
            {
                document.myform.txt.type=(document.myform.option.value=(document.myform.option.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution, you could use a ternary operator:

```js
$("#check").on("change", function(){
    $(this).is(":checked") ? $(".password").attr("type", "text") : $(".password").attr("type", "password");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" class="password" value="my"/>
<input type="password" class="password" value="password?"/><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id='check'> Show password
```